# Repeat region on jQuery BlockUI script fails to work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-blockui

I am trying to use repeat region on the jQuery BlockUI script but it fails to work.

This is the code I am using now:

```
    <?php do { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#t<?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?>').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#q<?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?>'), css: { width: '1024px' } }); 
        }); 

        $('#yes').click(function() { 
            // update the block message 
            $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" }); 

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'wait.php', 
                cache: false, 
                complete: function() { 
                    // unblock when remote call returns 
                    $.unblockUI(); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 

        $('#no').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
            return false; 
        }); 

    }); 
</script> 
<?php } while ($row_dd31 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd31)); ?>
```

Why does it not work?

Can one not use PHP repeat region alongside JavaScript? If not are there any alternatives to be used?

---

This is the code for the modal dialog:

```
<!-- modal -->              

<?php do { ?>
<div id="q<?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?>" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
<h3>Driver <?php echo $row_dd31['dNo']; ?></h3><p>
<input type="button" id="yes" value="Save" style="width: 75px; height: 50px;"/> <input type="button" id="no" value="Exit" style="width: 75px; height: 50px;"/> 
</div> 
<?php } while ($row_dd31 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd31)); ?>
```

This is how the tiles are generated:

```
<tr height="100px" align="center">        
            <?php do { ?>
            <td style="background-color: <?php echo $row_dd1['colour']; ?>;">   
              <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>">
              <button type="submit" class="link" id="t<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?></span></button>
            </td>
            <?php } while ($row_dd1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd1)); ?>
        </tr>
```

Comment: This old question appears to have been abandoned with no answer accepted, and comment threads not having been resolved. I wonder if this should be closed as unclear?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to generate jQuery to suit each custom row id, this works in theory however I would say that it is pretty bad application design. I would suggest writing a simple script that can handle all of your rows at once eg.

```
<div class="my-row-to-bind-jquery-to" id="xyz">...</div>
<div class="my-row-to-bind-jquery-to" id="xyz1">...</div>
<div class="my-row-to-bind-jquery-to" id="xyz2">...</div>
<div class="my-row-to-bind-jquery-to" id="xyz3">...</div>
```

then you can simply bind the blocking and unblocking of the ui to the class rather than each individual id like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-row-to-bind-jquery-to').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;

    // do the rest of your stuff here
  });
});
```

Comment: i need it done for about 400 rows. is this possible?

Comment: i have added the code i am using for the modal window

Comment: yeah of course, I don't see any problem with that, just make sure your rows all have the same class and then you can handle your ui blocking and unblocking by binding to that class, also for your reference it a better id to put all your rows into a parent container and give it an id, this way you can then pass JQuery a context to look for like so $('.my-row-to-bind-jquery-to', '#parent-row-container').click(function() {});. This is much better because JQuery does not have traverse the whole document to look for matching elements because you have given it a container to look in. All the best

Comment: im still a bit confused, nothing seems to be working. i will paste what i have done so far as a reply to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok would you able to elaborate on what the

```
$.blockUI({ message: **$('#parent-row-container')** ...
```

is supposed to be?

Also, are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: it has to echo a unique identifier. it needs to do this 300 times so that there are 300 unique instances of block UI. i hope you can understand what i mean...

Comment: so you have php that is generating hidden ui components that get used when a tile is clicked?

Comment: yes i will paste the code below

Comment: ok i have added the code to the original question, it shows how the tiles are generated. 300 are created. i need a unique instance of blockUI for each.

Comment: i have never done anything like this in php/jquery so it is really challenging

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224355/creating-300-instances-of-blockui